# Objective-C iOS Radar-like map

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, mapkit

I'm trying to create a radar like map for an iOS application. Something like one of these but for a map on a much smaller scale using GPS points.

[image: Radar Image]
[image: Radar Image 2]

I need to be able to change the color fluidly from blue to green to yellow to orange to red.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you need a Map Kit overlay. See these links for informations: 1. [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlay_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKOverlay)
2. [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/HazardMap/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: What have you tried so far? This looks like it would be straightforward to accomplish with a couple of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider designing a custom map or map overlay in [TileMill](http://tilemill.com), then using the [Mapbox mobile tools](http://mapbox.com/mobile) to display them natively.